# View contents of file in windows machine on to linux shell

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

Is there a way for me to view the contents of a file that is stored in my local windows machine into my linux putty session without copying the file into linux first?

I was thinking that I could ssh into windows and write a windows command to do it, but I'm not sure how to go about ssh'ing into my local windows machine in the first place.

Comment: You'd need a local ssh server on your MS-Windows system, not really the thing you are looking for. Question is what _exactly_ you mean by "view the contents"... If you want to access the contents, then you need that data on the system you want to access it. It is irrelevant how it get's there, you it has to be there. So the _real_ question here probably is: _how_ do you want to transfer that file? you could also think if sharing a file system between both systems, so a network mount.

Comment: So take another linux machine for example, I can view the contents of a file on that server from another one by doing `ssh username@server cat somefile.txt ` by doing this, I'm not copying the file into my server first, I'm just viewing the contents of somefile.txt through ssh, I want to do this with my local machine, that's what I need help with.

Comment: You seem to confuse a few things here. In that example `somefile.txt` has to be a file locally stored on the ssh server you connect to. That means it is already there, it has already been transferred or it has been generated there. You can _not_ somehow "magically visualize" a files content on a system where that content is not present.

Comment: Yes, and in my case there is a file on my windows machine, not magically, it is just there. I want to now ssh into my windows machine to view that file without having to copy it from windows onto linux first. How would I do this?

Comment: This I answered in my first comment: you would need to install a ssh server on your MS-Windows system, open the corresponding ports in your firewalls and make an ssh login from Linux to MS-Windows. Possible, but _very_ exotic.